# Identifying all the entries within 7 days of some dates (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes.

One records the date of trades:

```
trade = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-08-31', '2019-09-01', '2019-09-04'], 
                      'person': [1, 1,  2],
                      'code': [123, 123, 456],
                      'value1': [1, 2, 3]})
```

And the other records the dates of browsing history:

```
view = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-08-29', '2019-08-29', '2019-08-30', '2019-08-31', '2019-09-01',   '2019-09-01', '2019-09-01', '2019-09-02', '2019-09-03'], 
                      'person': [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2],
                      'code': [123, 456, 123, 456, 123, 123, 456, 123, 456],
                      'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
                    })
```

My desired outcome is to generate a list of the related browsing history (occurred within 7 days prior to the trade) for each trade.

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-08-31', '2019-09-01', '2019-09-04'], 
                      'person': [1, 1,  2],
                      'code': [123, 123, 456],
                      'value1': [1, 2, 3],
                       'view_dates': [['2019-08-29', '2019-08-29'], ['2019-08-29', '2019-08-30', '2019-09-01'], 
                                      ['2019-08-31', '2019-09-01', '2019-09-03']],
                       'view_values':[[1, 3], [1, 3, 5], [4, 7, 9]]})
```

I tried to use merge_asof to match the views with the trades. And then generate the list for each trade based on the merged outcome.

```
merge_out = pd.merge_asof(view, trade,
    tolerance=pd.Timedelta('7d'), direction='forward', 
    on='date', by = ['person', 'code'])
```

However, merge_asof uses each view entry only once.

It assigns views [1, 3] to trade 1, and views [5] to trade 2.

I want to assign views [1, 3] to trade 1, and views [1, 3, 5] to trade 2.

I am wondering whether there is a way to identify all the items in a time range in view for each trade. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no highly efficient way to do this in pure pandas, you can however use [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor)'s [`conditional_join`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) with a helper column, then [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
import janitor

trade['date'] = pd.to_datetime(trade['date'])
view['date'] = pd.to_datetime(view['date'])

out = (trade
  .assign(start_date=lambda d: d['date'].sub(pd.DateOffset(days=7)))
  .conditional_join(view.rename(columns={'date': 'view_dates',
                                         'value': 'view_values'}),
                    ('start_date', 'view_dates', '<='),
                    ('date', 'view_dates', '>='),
                    ('person', 'person', '=='),
                    ('code', 'code', '=='),
                    right_columns=['view_dates', 'view_values']
                   )
  .drop(columns='start_date')
  .assign(view_dates=lambda d: d['view_dates'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
  .groupby(list(trade), as_index=False).agg(list)  
)
```

A pure pandas solution would be less efficient as one would need to merge all combinations of the same person/code:

```
out = (trade
 .merge(view.rename(columns={'date': 'view_dates', 'value': 'view_values'}),
        on=['person', 'code'])
 .loc[lambda d: d['date'].gt(d['view_dates']) & 
      d['date'].sub(pd.DateOffset(days=7)).le(d['view_dates'])
     ]
 .assign(view_dates=lambda d: d['view_dates'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
 .groupby(list(trade), as_index=False).agg(list)  
)
```

Output:

```
        date  person  code  value1                            view_dates view_values
0 2019-08-31       1   123       1              [2019-08-29, 2019-08-30]      [1, 3]
1 2019-09-01       1   123       2  [2019-08-29, 2019-08-30, 2019-09-01]   [1, 3, 5]
2 2019-09-04       2   456       3  [2019-08-31, 2019-09-01, 2019-09-03]   [4, 7, 9]
```

Comment: i've been thinking about list arrays for a while, just havent figured out how to do it efficiently for conditional_join. it's use in SQL (array_agg, etc) is fascinating